# array pointers to structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct inventory{
    int ID;
    char name[20];
    int value;
};


int main()
{
    struct inventory *inv;

    inv = malloc(sizeof(1));

    inv[0].ID = 10;
    strcpy(inv[0].name,"hello charlie old mate");
    inv[0].value = 20;

    inv[1].ID = 20;

    printf("%d", inv[1].ID);

    return 0;
   }
```

Can you tell me how can `inv[1].ID` be set up to 20. When I allocated just 1 byte of memory for `inv`. How can it carry data of multiple structures?

Comment: Have you ever heard about *undefined behavior*?

Comment: " When i allocated just 1 byte of memory for inv. " is false.  Code allocated `sizeof(1)` bytes which is certainly not 1, but more likely 4.

Comment: just to elaborate what @chux sir said, `sizeof` considers the data type, not the _value_, a literal `1` is of type `int`. :)

Comment: "I paid for one parking space, but then I parked lots of cars on that space and some adjacent ones. How can that be? I only paid for one space."

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy let me know whether you are able to find your car there tomorrow morning. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: When I came back next day, some of my cars had been towed, some had been stolen, and someone had parked a truck on top of one of them so it was flat! Only the one on the parking sport I paid for was still there! Actually, I could turn this into a nice answer about undefined behavior, but someone already did that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy did you forget to mention that the _legit_ one was having scratches all over it due to the towing process?

Comment: I thought you weren't allowed to run with the ball in basketball, but I tried it and it worked. what is going on and why did the other players get angry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Can you tell me how can inv[1].ID be set up to 20. When I allocated just 1 byte of memory for inv. How can it carry data of multiple structures?*

**TL;DR** It cannot.

What you're seeing is invalid access of memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There is nothing in C standard that prevents you from from writing a code accessing invalid memory, but as soon as you do that, *voila!!*

The memory allocated to `inv` (by calling `malloc(1)`) is *way less* then it should be. Thus, basically, you're trying to access memory that does not belong to you (your process) and hence that memory is *invalid*. Any attempt to access invalid memory results in UB.

Following the same trail, even after you have allocated proper memory for `inv`, then also

```
 strcpy(inv[0].name,"hello charlie old mate");
```

will be UB, as you're trying to copy more than `20` elements into the destination having only size of 20 (which can hold 19 valid `chars` + 1 null terminator, if you want `name` to be used as a *string*). Count your memory requirement properly and stay within bounds.

That said, always check for the return value of `malloc()` for success before using the returned pointer.

Comment: I do know what u mean i shout allocate inv = malloc(sizeof(struct inventory));

So it should make the pointer access just one struct inv[0]

though even when i add more to inv[1],(...) inv[5]

it compiles and gives certainly some strange answers. Look my comment to the top with a prtscr

Comment: @FenixxReborn Yes, or. for better, `inv = malloc(sizeof *inv);`

Comment: @FenixxReborn for the edited part, you __must__ know the size of allocation and access accordingly. Again, C won't stop you from accessing `inv[5]` while you';re allocated only for 1 element, but it will lead to UB.

Comment: I added values just to some of the struct parts. It attached 0 to all of them. Without any initialization. This is strange, don't understand this at all. As there should be garbage as i think? The UB doesnt yeld bad results by accessing this memory. Though, when i create more valid data in my program it could be taken by that, right? So finally when i want to create a valid pointer array to structures i should realloc them by n * sizeof(struct inventory) and then i can call them by the calls inv[1] and inv[2]. Am i right?

Comment: @FenixxReborn basically yes. But keep in mind, `malloc()` returns unitialized memory, the content in indeterminate. and yes, `0` is very much a garbage value (in this context), just like `4537921636` or `-62490936`

Comment: Thanks. I was certailny dumb. Though the formated 0 output for like 20 structures i printed. Made me think of it could initialize it somehow. Now im sure its just luky garbage. Saved my evening sir.

Comment: @FenixxReborn Happy it helped. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is undefined behaviour in your code -

```
inv = malloc(sizeof(1));      // you allocate size of int
inv[0].ID = 10;
strcpy(inv[0].name,"hello charlie old mate");    //copying more than your buffer can hold
```

You allocate size equal to that of `int` and is not enough for structure and access unauthorized memory.And then the `strcpy`, you try to store more contents than the space available. `name` can contain `19` characters and `'\0'` at end. And the string you copy is larger then `19` characters.